# Plotting Takagi function with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've started with matplotlib a week ago; I'm trying to plot the function

[image]

where

[image]

I changed my code for

```
from math import*
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def phi(x):
    return min(ceil(x) - x, x - floor(x))

n=50
    def f(x):
        return sum([phi(x*2.0**i)/(2.0**i) for i in range (1,n)])

t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.1)
plt.plot(t, map(f,t))
plt.show()
```

But it is not working. The error that I'm getting is:

```
File "C:\Documents and Settings\Macedo\Desktop\exem.py", line 15, in <module>
    plt.plot(t, map(f,t))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2459, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 3850, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 325, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 302, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 242, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

Comment: Should `phi` include a `return` statement?  As is, it looks like it's not returning anything.

Comment: I've tried to change 'lambda' for 'return', but it not worked either.

Comment: At what point do you mean to truncate your sum?

Comment: @katrielalex, why is necessary truncate the sum?

Comment: Try `list(map(f, t))` instead of `map(f, t)`. `map` in Python 3 returns an iterator, so maybe that's confusing it.

Comment: @ThomasK, it worked. But the graphic is very low in quality; is there a way to improve it?

Comment: @PauloHenrique: well, you can't compute a sum to infinity -- it would take infinitely long! Usually the way you compute them is to decree that you cut off the tail.

Comment: "low in quality": You'll need to post an example or be more specific.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is how you are defining variables. For example, you wrote:

```
def phi(x):
    phi = lambda x: min(ceil(x) - x, x - floor(x))
```

You can either define it as

```
def phi(x):
    return min(ceil(x) - x, x - floor(x))
```

or

```
phi = lambda x: min(ceil(x) - x, x - floor(x))
```

Look up function definitions and lambda functions in Python.

The definition of `f` should not be in a loop. So ou need something like

```
n=50
def f(x):
    return sum([phi(x*2.0**i)/(2.0**i) for i in range (1,n)])
```

To get rid of the "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" error, use

```
plt.plot(t, map(f,t))
```

instead of

```
plt.plot(t, f(t))
```

The problem is that `math.ceil` needs a scalar, and does not operate element-wise on arrays, which is what you want. So `map` will operate `f` element-wise on `t` now.

So finally, the code I am using is:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def phi(x):
    return min(ceil(x) - x, x - floor(x))

n=50
def f(x):
    return sum([phi(x*2.0**i)/(2.0**i) for i in range (1,n)])

t = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.1)
plt.plot(t, map(f,t))
plt.show()
```

And the output is

[image]

This is in Python 2.7.2. As suggested by @ThomasK, for Python 3 you might need `list(map(f,t))`.

Comment: a type error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @highBandWidth: alternatively, he could write `f = np.vectorize(f)`.  He might also want to use linspace instead of arange, to get the upper bound naturally.

Comment: You also have to change the definition of the other function f similarly. Why is the definition in a loop?

Comment: @highBandWidth, I changed the definition of f, but I'm the same error that is in my post.